# Hide ion-nav-bar on scroll in ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having tabs template in ionic.Need to hide top navigation bar on scrolling the content of tab.Like whatsapp does.
What changes needed in my template.

```
<!--This is Index.html-->
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive"></ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
<!--this is template.html-->
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="x in names" type="item-text-wrap">
                <img ng-src="{{x.displayProfile}}">
                <h2>{{x.firstName}}</h2>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/; trigger $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false) inside scroll listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it in custom situations.

```
<ion-content on-scroll="scrollEvent()" delegate-handle="scrollHandle">
```

Set the on-scroll event to the ionic-content and then in your controller.

```
$scope.scrollEvent = function() {
  $scope.scrollamount = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('scrollHandle').getScrollPosition().top;
  if ($scope.scrollamount > 180) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
       $scope.hideNavigation = true;
    });
  } else {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.hideNavigation = false;
    });
  }
};
```

IF YOU HAVE SIMPLE NAV BAR AND CAN HIDE IT ALL TOGETHER JUST USE "$ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false);" instead of $scope.hideNavgiation and all related things to that variable. Example:

```
$scope.scrollEvent = function() {
  var scrollamount = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('scrollHandle').getScrollPosition().top;
  if (scrollamount > 0) { // Would hide nav-bar immediately when scrolled and show it only when all the way at top. You can fiddle with it to find the best solution for you
    $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false);
  } else {
    $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(true);
  }
}
```

The $scope.scrollamount is just a pixel value of when to hide the navbar, in this case when user has scrolled 180px from the top. But after this you only need to add ng-if="!hideNavigation" or ng-show="!hideNavigation".

You can also set $scope.scrollamount to zero/null when scope is destroyed or ionicview.leave etc.

If your navbar is not in the same template and/or controller as your template then you can just

```
$scope.scrollEvent = function() {
  $scope.scrollamount = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('scrollHandle').getScrollPosition().top;
  if ($scope.scrollamount > 180) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('showHideNavigation', { hide: true });
    });
  } else {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('showHideNavigation', { hide: false });
    });
  }
};
```

And catch it in your other controller

```
$scope.$on('showHideNavigation', function(event, args) {
  $scope.hideNavigation = args.hide;
});
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to contribute for **Ionic 2** users with something I've made.

You just need to add it to your project. You can customize HeaderScroller component after that:

**header-scroller.ts**:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Show/Hide header based on page's scroll position.
 */
@Directive({
    selector: '[header-scroller]'
})
export class HeaderScroller {

    /**
     * @var number Distance from page top to trigger the hide/show functionality.
     */
    protected _topTriggeringDistance: number = 100;

    /**
     * @var string Distance to keep between the top and the content when the header is hidden.
     */
    protected _topContentDistance: string = '10px';

    /**
     * @var number Animation transition, in seconds, for showing/hiding the header.
     */
    protected _animationTransition: number = 0.6;

    /**
     * @var HTMLElement Content element (<ion-content>).
     */
    protected _el: any;

    /**
     * Initializes.
     *
     * @param el ElementRef Directive's selector.
     * @return void
     */
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {

        this._el = el.nativeElement;
    }

    /**
     * Binds the scroller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    ngOnInit() {

        // Set animation transition
        this._el.previousElementSibling.style.transition = `top ${this._animationTransition}s ease-in-out`;

        this._bindScroller(this._el.children[0]);
    }

    /**
     * Listen to scroll events in <scroll-content> component.
     *
     * @param el HTMLElement Scroller element (<scroll-content>).
     * @return void
     */
    protected _bindScroller(el): void {

        el.addEventListener('scroll', event => {

            let scroller = event.target,
                header = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling;

            if (event.target.scrollTop > this._topTriggeringDistance && header.style.top != '0') {
                scroller.style.marginTop = this._topContentDistance;
                header.style.top = `-${header.offsetHeight}px`;
            } else if (event.target.scrollTop <= this._topTriggeringDistance && header.style.top == `-${header.offsetHeight}px`) {
                header.style.top = '0';
                scroller.style.marginTop = `${header.offsetHeight}px`;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In your **page.ts**:

```
import { HeaderScroller } from 'path/to/header-scroller';
```

Depending on your Ionic version (beta or stable), you must add:

```
// Ionic 2 beta (page.ts)
@Component({
    directives: [ HeaderScroller ]
})

// Ionic 2 new (app.module.ts) -untested, but it should work-
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HeaderScroller
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        HeaderScroller
    ]
})
```

And in your **page.html**

```
<ion-content header-scroller>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Putting it also into entryComponents, results in an error. Also, it works only if scrolling to top, not when scrolling up.

Comment: @alex351 It works for my beta version of Ionic (2.0.0-beta.11). It's implemented in my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.besmartmobile.mundosocial What version of Ionic do you have?

Comment: I have beta.1. Anyways, I chose another method, because your code does show the header only if scrolling to top, not immediately when scrolling up. Furthermore, I had to select "this._el.children[1]".

Comment: That's right. If you found another solution or you were be able to improve this code, please let us know too. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I am not getting output